# Is there a limit to the amount of space an application can use to store data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I see that apple has implemented a max size for the actual application but is there a limit to the amount of data you can store with your application or is it only limited by the amount of free space on the device?

Comment: It's only limited by the amount of free space on the device. To verify this, write a simple app that just dumps a bunch of "data" to the disk and see what happens.

Comment: Are you referring to an IPhone app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only limited by the amount of free space on disk; **however**, using up excessive disk space will really annoy your users (since it will limit the amount of apps they can install on their device). Therefore, if you are looking to get good reviews, it is advisable to keep your usage of disk space down to a minimum.

Comment: Thanks and noted, I keep the user apprised of how much space they're using (and is available) and give the ability to purge stored files.