# What are the storage limits for iPod/iPad applications?

Tags: iphone, caching, ipad, storage

I'm not talking about binary size. I'm talking about the amount of data that can be written to disk during execution inside of certain directories such as Cache or Documents.

I can't find an easy answer in the XCode documentation, which is to say I can find none at all.

I know there is a limit for the cache directory in the form of "oh hey, your device is crashing now", but I haven't determined the actual number, and I am not sure if the Documents folders or other folders have the same restrictions.

Links and numbers are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a limit to the amount of space an application can use to store data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619393/is-there-a-limit-to-the-amount-of-space-an-application-can-use-to-store-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reference or limitation of disk space once the application has been installed to the iPhone, iPad, or iPod Touch device.

The only limitation would be available disk space (whole disk space available) at time of writing to those directories.